# How to split a chron date & time object in zoo for aggregation

Tags: r

I have imported data with a five minute interval into a zoo object, where the index is a chron with both date and time:

```
> d
(09/09/09 16:45:10)  13.2  5.8
(09/09/09 16:50:10)   8.3  0.7
(09/09/09 16:55:10)   4.7  0.7
(09/09/09 17:00:10)   6.6  0.7
(09/09/09 17:05:10)   4.6  0.7
```

I am trying to aggregate by quarter hour intervals.

I found way to do so by converting back to a string, but the output is no longer a zoo.

```
> r =data.frame(aggregate(d,trunc(chron(times=substr(as.character(index(d)),11,18)),"00:15:00"), mean)
> r
00:00:00   0.5644444
00:15:00   0.5400000
00:30:00   0.5488889
00:45:00   0.6155556
01:00:00   0.3422222
```

While I can plot this, I was trying to do this natively. I found that aggregate with zoo could do day and hour, but I could not subdivide the hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given Shane's idea, I've change it a bit... The original question was how to aggregate on the minutes in the hours involved and get rid of the date. Also since the math didn't like midnight earlier, I'm using string parsing.

```
# Where X is a zoo obj with chron timestamps containing both time & date
# and min is like "00:30:00" for half hour intervals
> trunc.chrontime = function (x, min)
  {
    if (!inherits(x, "times")) 
        x = as.chron(x)
    s = substr(as.character(x),11,18)
    c = chron(times=s)
    trunc(c,min)
  }

> s = aggregate(d,trunc.minstr(index(d),"00:30:00"),mean)
s
00:00:00  0.5522222 0.4988889 0.006666667
00:30:00  0.5822222 0.5366667 0.012222222
01:00:00  0.3388889 0.4455556 0.000000000
01:30:00  0.3422222 0.4344444 0.000000000
02:00:00  0.3366667 0.4366667 0.000000000 ...
```

Comment: That works too.  You don't mention getting rid of dates in your question, although it would be easy to change mine to do that (just return times from the function instead of a chron object).

Comment: You are correct, though in my sample data I tried to illustrate that. That was half of my original problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that there's any way to do this built into zoo or chron, but you can create your own function by using a little math.  Here you go:

```
trunc.minutes <- function (x, n.minutes) 
{
    if (!inherits(x, "times")) 
        x <- as.chron(x)
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    sec <- round(24 * 3600 * abs(x - floor(x)))
    h <- (sec%/%(n.minutes*60))/(60/n.minutes)
    hour <- as.integer(h)
    minutes <- (h %% hour) * 60
    chron(dates=chron::dates(x), times=times(paste(hour, minutes, "00", sep=":")))
}
```

Here's an example of the usage:

```
dts <- chron::dates(c("02/27/92", "02/27/92", "01/14/92",
                "02/28/92", "02/01/92"))
tms <- times(c("23:03:20", "23:29:56", "01:03:30",
                "18:21:03", "16:56:26"))     
x <- chron(dates = dts, times = tms) # original dates
x
[1] (02/27/92 23:03:20) (02/27/92 22:29:56) (01/14/92 01:03:30)
[4] (02/28/92 18:21:03) (02/01/92 16:56:26)
trunc.minutes(x, 15) # new dates at 15 minute intervals
[1] (02/27/92 23:00:00) (02/27/92 22:15:00) (01/14/92 01:00:00)
[4] (02/28/92 18:15:00) (02/01/92 16:45:00)
trunc.minutes(x, 30) # new dates at 30 minute intervals
[1] (02/27/92 23:00:00) (02/27/92 22:00:00) (01/14/92 01:00:00)
[4] (02/28/92 18:00:00) (02/01/92 16:30:00)
```

Lastly, you can now use this function to aggregate the data:

```
ts.zoo <- zoo(rnorm(5), x) # a zoo time series
```

Or just use these new dates for aggregation (see how it rolls up the second example since there are two values in that window):

```
> aggregate(ts.zoo, trunc.minutes(x, 15), mean)
(01/14/92 01:00:00) (02/01/92 16:45:00) (02/27/92 23:00:00) (02/27/92 23:15:00) 
         -0.6738659          -0.4844803           0.7968155          -1.3571121 
(02/28/92 18:15:00) 
          0.7625861 
> aggregate(ts.zoo, trunc.minutes(x, 30), mean)
(01/14/92 01:00:00) (02/01/92 16:30:00) (02/27/92 23:00:00) (02/28/92 18:00:00) 
         -0.6738659          -0.4844803          -0.2801483           0.7625861
```

Comment: I agree that there doesn't appear to be a built-in method for time, only date. I just noticed that the math doesn't like military time (hour 00 results in NA). Perhaps the string approach I was using would work with a wrapper function to make it back into a chron.

Comment: I updated my example.  You can use aggregate on the zoo object as in the above.

Answer (score 2):

chron has a trunc.times method so we can do this:

```
library(zoo)
library(chron)
z <- zoo(1:5, 
   chron(c("02/27/92", "02/27/92", "01/14/92", "02/28/92", "02/01/92"),
   c("23:03:20", "23:29:56", "01:03:30", "18:21:03", "16:56:26")))
aggregate(z, function(x) trunc(x, "00:15:00"), mean)
```