# What is the simplest method to fill the area under a geom_freqpoly line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The x-axis is time broken up into time intervals.  There is an *interval* column in the data frame that specifies the time for each row.  The column is a factor, where each interval is a different factor level.

Plotting a histogram or line using geom_histogram and geom_freqpoly works great, but I'd like to have a line, like that provided by geom_freqpoly, with the area filled.

Currently I'm using geom_freqpoly like this:

```
ggplot(quake.data, aes(interval, fill=tweet.type)) + geom_freqpoly(aes(group = tweet.type, colour = tweet.type)) + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-60, hjust=0, size = 6))
```

[image: plots]

I would prefer to have a filled area, such as provided by `geom_density`, but without smoothing the line:

[image: smoooth]

The `geom_area` has been suggested, is there any way to use a ggplot2-generated statistic, such as ..count.., for the geom_area's y-values?  Or, does the count aggregation need to occur prior to using ggplot2?

---

As stated in the answer, geom_area(..., stat = "bin") is the solution:

```
ggplot(quake.data, aes(interval)) + geom_area(aes(y = ..count.., fill = tweet.type, group = tweet.type), stat = "bin") + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-60, hjust=0, size = 6))
```

produces:

[image: desired]

Comment: if you're already doing intervals are you sure you want a smooth curve?

Comment: No, I was just exploring the ggplot2 geoms that would produce the filled area.  I'd prefer the geom_freqpoly, but with a filled area.

I'm guessing geom_area will get that but I'll have to manually aggregate the frequency count.

Comment: Actually, is there a reason you're using a factor instead of a date time variable?

Comment: No reason.  I was having difficulty getting some of the time series packages to work and I ended up doing something similar to what was mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441136/what-is-an-efficient-method-for-partitioning-and-aggregating-intervals-from-times

Is there a benefit in converting them to datetimes?  This project has been my first extensive use of R, hence the violation of idioms.

Comment: This question is discussed [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302890/881272).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
geom_area(aes(y = ..count..), stat = "bin")
```

Comment: Thank you, I've used 'stat = "bin"' before but forgot about it.  I need to buy your book.  =)

Answer (score 3):

`geom_ribbon` can be used to produce a filled area between two lines without needing to explicitly construct a polygon. There is good documentation [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_ribbon.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're aiming for. Do you want a line or bars. You should check out [geom_bar](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html) for filled bars. Something like:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = count))
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

If you want a line filled in underneath then you should look at [geom_area](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_ribbon.html) which I haven't personally used but it appears the construct will be almost the same.

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = count))
p + geom_area()
```

Hope that helps. Give some more info and we can probably be more helpful.

Actually i would throw on an index, just the row of the data and use that as x, and then use

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = index, y = count))
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + scale_x_continuous("Intervals", 
breaks = index, labels = intervals)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot(quake.data, aes(interval, fill=tweet.type, group = 1)) + geom_density()`

But I don't think this is a meaningful graphic.

Comment: After seeing it, I agree.  I'll update my question to clarify that I'm looking for a geom_freqpoly plot with a filled area.  

It looks like geom_area would work, but is it possible to use ggplot2 provided statistics (e.g., ..count..) for y-axis values?