# Match intervals with events in R

Tags: r

I have an event table and a set of intervals. I want to associate a boolean with each event, that is set to T is the event is in the interval.

My inputs:

```
intervals:
begin                      end
2015-03-01 14:02:00        2015-03-01 14:09:00
2015-03-01 15:13:00        2015-03-01 15:54:00
2015-03-01 16:02:00        2015-03-01 19:09:00

events:
id           date
1            2015-03-01 14:01:00
2            2015-03-01 14:03:00
3            2015-03-01 14:07:00
4            2015-03-01 15:55:00
5            2015-03-01 17:02:00
```

My output would be:

```
id           inInterval
1            F
2            T
3            T
4            F
5            T
```

I have millions of events and tens of thousands of intervals. For performance reasons I don't want to loop on the events and I don't want to process all events for each interval.

What I can easily do is get on ordered data.table of events and intervals start/end:

```
events:
id           date                     start       end
1            2015-03-01 14:01:00      
NA           2015-03-01 14:02:00      T
2            2015-03-01 14:03:00
3            2015-03-01 14:07:00
NA           2015-03-01 14:09:00                  T
NA           2015-03-01 15:13:00      T
NA           2015-03-01 15:54:00                  T
4            2015-03-01 15:55:00
NA           2015-03-01 16:02:00      T
5            2015-03-01 17:02:00
NA           2015-03-01 19:09:00                  T
```

Now I am stuck on the last part: setting inInterval=T for all lines between a start=T and a end=T. It clearly requires some kind of lag, but I am missing the required feature.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**: It seems that this existing question provides some insights: [What is an efficient method for partitioning and aggregating intervals from timestamped rows in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441136/what-is-an-efficient-method-for-partitioning-and-aggregating-intervals-from-time/)
It was suggested once I published my question. Basically findInterval should help me solve my issue.

Comment: May be check `foverlaps` from `data.table`

Comment: have you tried a simple ifelse statement? `ifelse( date < begin | date > end, F, T)`

Comment: @akrun It looks exactly like what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @grrgrrbla That solution works with a single interval. With multiple intervals it is doable, but you need to call ifelse on all events for each interval, that's what I don't want.

Comment: What's the dates in your data? Are they of `POSIXct` class? Also, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Anyway, if the format is good, as suggested by akrun, you could do something like `setkey(setDT(intervals))  ; setkey(setDT(events)[, date2 := date], date, date2) ; foverlaps(events, intervals, which = TRUE)` with the `data.table` package.

Comment: and `events[,inInterval := !is.na(foverlaps(events, intervals, type="within", which=T)$yid)][,  .(id, inInterval)]` to have exactly the desired output

Answer (score 1):

My newbie idea in base R (given the intervals table is ordered and that there's no overlapping intervals):

```
pint <- as.POSIXct(as.vector(t(intervals)))
results <- data.frame(
            id = events$id,
            inInterval = findInterval( as.POSIXct(events$date), pint) %% 2 != 0
         )
```

Gives:

```
  id inInterval
1  1      FALSE
2  2       TRUE
3  3       TRUE
4  4      FALSE
5  5       TRUE
```

`findInterval` return the index in the intervals found:

- if it's odd, we're in a real interval return TRUE
- if it's even we're outside real intervals. return FALSE

Answer (score 0):

With [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/) and `iv_between()`:

```r
library(ivs)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

intervals <- tibble(
  begin = c(
    "2015-03-01 14:02:00",
    "2015-03-01 15:13:00",
    "2015-03-01 16:02:00"
  ),
  end = c(
    "2015-03-01 14:09:00",
    "2015-03-01 15:54:00",
    "2015-03-01 19:09:00"
  )
)

intervals <- intervals %>%
  mutate(
    begin = as.POSIXct(begin, tz = "UTC"),
    end = as.POSIXct(end, tz = "UTC")
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    range = iv(begin, end),
    .keep = "unused"
  )

events <- tibble(
  id = 1:5,
  date = c(
    "2015-03-01 14:01:00",
    "2015-03-01 14:03:00",
    "2015-03-01 14:07:00",
    "2015-03-01 15:55:00",
    "2015-03-01 17:02:00"
  )
)

events <- events %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, tz = "UTC"))

intervals
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>                                        range
#>                                   <iv<dttm>>
#> 1 [2015-03-01 14:02:00, 2015-03-01 14:09:00)
#> 2 [2015-03-01 15:13:00, 2015-03-01 15:54:00)
#> 3 [2015-03-01 16:02:00, 2015-03-01 19:09:00)

events %>%
  mutate(in_interval = iv_between(date, intervals$range))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>      id date                in_interval
#>   <int> <dttm>              <lgl>      
#> 1     1 2015-03-01 14:01:00 FALSE      
#> 2     2 2015-03-01 14:03:00 TRUE       
#> 3     3 2015-03-01 14:07:00 TRUE       
#> 4     4 2015-03-01 15:55:00 FALSE      
#> 5     5 2015-03-01 17:02:00 TRUE
```